# How can I parameterize a class with an object's type to get an instance of it in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, parameterization

I'd like to parameterize a class with the type of an object to make my code more generic. By doing this, I don't need an implementation for all objects that extend a certain trait.

I have the following code that demonstrates my goal:

```
abstract trait Foo {
  def greet
}

object Coo extends Foo {
  def greet = println("Coo!")
}

object Boo extends Foo {
  def greet = println("Boo!")
}

class A[Fooer <: Foo] {
  def moo = asInstanceOf[Fooer].greet()
}

object Main extends App {
  new A[Coo.type].moo() // hopefully prints "Coo!"
}
```

The code is throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to Foo
```

And I believe it's because of the `asInstanceOf` call which is seemingly using `this` implicitly.

Essentially my question is this: how can I get an instance of my object by type within a class via parameterization?

Comment: you may also find this of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441410/scala-generic-function-return-type/40448371#40448371

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I believe it's because of the `asInstanceOf` call which is seemingly using `this` implicitly.

*Every* class in Scala extends `Any`, which inherits the special method `asInstanceOf`, among other things. I wouldn't say it's happening *implicitly*--it's just that you're calling a member method of that class, which is calling it on itself. Same as if you wrote `def moo = greet`.

Furthermore, any time you use `asInstanceOf`, you're asking the compiler to lie to itself and keep going. This will more often than not result in a `ClassCastException`. In this case, it's because you're attempting to cast an instance `A` into some unknown sub-type of `Foo`. This will never work. In the very specific case, you're attempting to pass the singleton type `Coo.type` to an instance of `A` and then create a *new* instance of `Coo.type`. While there are many other reasons why this won't work, one of them is that you can't create a second instance of a singleton type--it's called that for a reason.

More generally, you don't *know* that you can simply construct an object given a type. A type doesn't have a constructor, a *class* does.

This might be a side-effect of being a simplified example, but you're concerned with creating an instance of `A` with some type parameter without needing to pass it an actual object, but the objects you're concerned with already exist. So why not pass them?

```
class A[Fooer <: Foo](f: Fooer) {
  def moo = f.greet
}
```

The only other way to do this is to provide evidence that `Fooer` can be constructed. There are no *type* constraints for proving something is a constructable class, though. What you can do is require a `Class` meta object instead:

```
class A[Fooer <: Foo](clazz: Class[Fooer]) {
  def moo = clazz.newInstance.greet
}
```

This is crude, however. First, it doesn't work with your singleton types above (because they can't be constructed again). And second, we can only call `newInstance` when there are no constructor parameters to provide, and there's no way to enforce that.

So while this will work:

```
scala> class Bar extends Foo { def greet = print("Bar") }

scala> new A(classOf[Bar]).moo
Bar
```

The following will not:

```
scala> class Baz(i: Int) extends Foo { def greet = println("Baz") }
defined class Baz

scala> new A(classOf[Baz]).moo
java.lang.InstantiationException: Baz

scala> new A(classOf[Coo.type]).moo
<console>:14: error: class type required but Coo.type found
       new A(classOf[Coo.type]).moo
                        ^
```

---

Alternatively, you might use a type class that allows you to consistently build instances of `Foo`, but that would require creating one for each sub-class. e.g.:

```
trait FooBuilder[A] {
    def build(): A
}

implicit object BarBuilder extends FooBuilder[Bar] {
    def build() = new Bar
}

class A[Fooer <: Foo](implicit fb: FooBuilder[Fooer]) {
    def moo = fb.build().greet
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I was hoping to avoid passing by a constructor, but I guess it's the best way to do it. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!